# How to avoid loops when iterating over adjacent elements of a vector

Tags: loops, functional-programming, iterator, rust

In Rust, how do I avoid writing these loops? The code takes a vector and multiplies three adjacent elements to a product. Hence, the outer loop goes over all elements that can form a group of three and the inner loop does the multiplication.

The difficulty lies, I think, in the incomplete iteration of the outer loop (from element `0` to `last - 3`). Further, the inner loop must use a sub-range.

Is there a way to avoid writing the loops?

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let mut products = Vec::new();
for seq in 0..v.len() - 3 {
    let mut product = 1;
    for offset in 0..3 {
        product *= v[seq + offset];
    }
    products.push(product);
}
```

Comment: Right now, all the calculated `product`s are discarded and nothing really happens. Do you want to collect all those products into a vector or what do you want to do with them?

Comment: You are right. That got lost during cuting my original code to the above example. I made an edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function you are searching for is [`[T]::windows()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows). You can specify the size of the overlapping windows and it will return an iterator over sub-slices.

You can obtain the product of all elements within a sub-slice by making an iterator out of it and using [`Iterator::product()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.product).

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let products: Vec<u64> = v.windows(3)
    .map(|win| win.iter().product())
    .collect();
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9413ca51b34eab18addf2b6bb006846a&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Here we collect all products into a new vector.

---

A last note: instead of writing down all numbers in the vector manually you *could* write this instead:

```
let v: Vec<_> = (1..10).chain(1..10).collect();
```